# Netcore2.2 app aborts in release configuration on a Linux machine

Tags: c#, .net-core, coreclr

Also logged: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/27734

Code attached: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/files/3820061/Program.zip

We have an issue with the attached (heavily cut down) project which targets netcoreapp2.2.

We build and publish the app in both Release and Debug configurations.

When running on Windows, Release and Debug both complete successfully.

When running on Linux, Debug completes successfully, however Release aborts with one of the following errors:

- System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'
- Segmentation fault

The program is very simple, contains no unmanaged code, no third party dependencies, and almost no logic at all.

Linux machine details (however this happens on all the different Linux machines / OSs available to us):

```
Operating system: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64
```

dotnet --info:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.402
 Commit:    c7f2f96116

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     centos
 OS Version:  7
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         centos.7-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.402/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.7
  Commit:  b1e29ae826

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.2.402 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.7 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.7 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.7 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

We have already cut down the program as far as we can (obviously in our actual program the method parameters are required).

Has anybody seen this issue or can suggest a way forward that doesn't involve removing parameters or removing the interfaces?

Comment: This is a runtime bug. The fix belongs in the runtime, not in your code, it looks like. The way forward is for someone to fix the runtime :)

Comment: how do you publish to linux?

Comment: @Darkonekt Using msbuild 16.0 with the Publish target on my local Windows machine (and then copy across to the linux box)

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks, I agree, probably the case, but just seeing if anyone knew any more specifics / had encountered it :)

Comment: I am not sure it is possible to build for linux using pure msbuild.  I know you need an SDK specific for the version you are trying to publish and run a dotnet build command with the target OS and target platform ( X64 )

Comment: Take a look at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build

Comment: When I deploy to linux i usually set the target to be for example dotnet build --runtime ubuntu.18.04-x64

Comment: When I do it that way or when I just hit right click Publish from Visual Studio and the profile has linux as the targer it just work on linux as long a s the .NET COre runtime is installed

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to this was that upgrading to net core 3.0 will solve most of the issues (there is still one hard to reproduce edge-case that Microsoft are investigating).

The long answer to this bug on the net core clr github page, but the summary by janvorli is the seen below:

"The issue was caused by a JIT bug. When Thing1::DoWork1 calls thing2.DoWork2 and passes the same arguments to it (except for the first one that was the thing2), it incorrectly shuffles the arguments from the incoming argument registers and stack slots to the DoWork2's argument registers and slots. Based on the Unix AMD64 calling convention, the parameters to DoWork1 are passed as follows:

```
            this in RDI  
            IThing2 thing2 in RSI  
            double[][] array1 in RDX  
            double[] array2 in RCX  
            int[] array3 in R8  
            int[] array4 in R9  
            double[] array5 in stack slot 0  
            int integer1 in stack slot 1  
            int integer2 in stack slot 2  
            int integer3 in stack slot 3  
            double double1 in XMM0
```

When it calls the `thing2.DoWork2(array1, double1, array3, array4, array5, integer1, integer2, integer3);`, the arguments should passed as follows:

```
            thing2 in RDI (was in RSI)  
            array1 in RSI (was in RDX)  
            double1 in XMM0 (was in XMM0)  
            int[] array3 in RDX (was in R8)  
            array4 in RCX (was in R9)  
            array5 in R8 (was in stack slot 0)  
            int integer1 in R9 (was in stack slot 1)  
            int integer2 in stack slot 0 (was in stack slot 2)  
            int integer3 in stack slot 1 (was in stack slot 3)
```

So as you can see, the JIT needs to do these argument moves:

```
RSI->RDI
RDX->RSI
R8->RDX
R9->RCX
Stack slot 0->R8
Stack slot 1->R9
Stack slot 2->stack slot 0
Stack slot 3->Stack slot 1
```

But in .NET 2.2, there was a bug in JIT that did the moves in an incorrect order. It moved 32 bit from stack slot 2 to stack slot 0 before moving stack slot 0 to R8. So the R8 (which should contain reference to array5) ended up having broken value and accessing it resulted in the crash in your testing app.

Unfortunately, I was unable to find the PR that fixed this problem."